# Codeigniter URL Routing failing in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a traditional MVC Codeigniter app and now to support versioning in the short terms i want to add htaccess rule that checks and redirects to a v1 folder inside the controller

here is what i tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^!/v1
RewriteRule . ^/v1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `!` (not) to come before the pattern in your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v1
```

Additionally, you need to capture the pattern in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v1/$1 [L]
```

The `^` means the beginning of the string, so it makes no sense to use it in your rule's target (unless you really wanted it to route to a URL starting with "^").